# How to post data from an android application to a wamp server?

Tags: android, server, http-post, wamp

I am trying to POST data using an **http request** method from an Android application to a Wamp server.

When I run the application a success message is shown on the Android app, but there is no data inserted in the table of the Wamp server. There is no error shown on logcat. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAdd;@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

}

public void insert(View view) {
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
    String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
    insertToDatabase(name, add);

}

private void insertToDatabase(String name, String add) {
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramAddress = params[1];
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", add));
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ip address of my system/Employee3/create_product.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, add);}
}
```

Comment: No code. No suggestion. Well one: post your code.

Comment: how can i post code??

Comment: You are returning "succes" even if there was a catch.

Answer (score 0):

For the Http debugging, I suggest you firstly use some tools to test the interface, such as curl or postMan. Make sure the post/get method work correct in these tools, then test the interface in Android